# Shell output in email content

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am executing a shell script and the output of the command is being stored in a variable. Post this i am also sending the email using editable email plugin.

I want to show the output of the shell command in the email content.

How to show $result in the email body?

```
result=`ssh paytmdev@10.100.9.25 './vikas-tesh.sh'` 
echo $result
```

Answer (score 0):

$result is available only for your shell step, and if you want to use it like jenkins variable ${result} then you can use an Env Inject Plugin.

- install plugin
- in a shell step add an echo

`echo "RESULT=$result" > ${WORKSPACE}/result.env`

and then use env inject plugin and point to result.env location, so in the email section you can access $result as a jenkins variable: ${RESULT}